# schedule two (or more) tasks to run at the same time (assuming cores are sufficient)

Tags: java, concurrency

Say I want to schedule 2 tasks to run at the same time.
How would I do this?

Here's what I've tried, but it only looks approximate

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask {
        String name;
        MyTask(String n) {
            name = n;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.err.println("from task " + name);

        }

    }


// now use the tasks
MyTask first = new MyTask("first");
MyTask second = new MyTask("second");
Timer t1 = new Timer();
Timer t2 = new Timer();

t1.schedule(first, 2); // wait "some" time?
t2.schedule(second, 0);
```

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService`

Comment: What do you think _same time_ means? Why _wait "some" time_?

Comment: *wait* sometime because the instruction could takes time to finish.

Comment: If I had put '0' for the first schedule call, it'd be run immediately, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is `2` that amount of time? How did you come up with that value?

Comment: Why do you need them to run at the same time? How strict are you about how 'simultaneous' they are? No main stream (non-specialized) operating system will allow you to force both of your threads to be run immediately and together.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); // 2 threads
Runnable first = new MyTask("first");
Runnable second = new MyTask("second");
es.submit(first);  // first starts running
es.submit(second); // second starts running in parallel
```

Comment: wont' these be run in order? (ie., FIFO ?)

Comment: It will be executed concurrently. The second runnable my finish first.

Comment: The above code does not guarantee any order of execution of the provided Runnable tasks.

Comment: No it does not. Why should it? The two runnable are executed in parallel, "at the same time" as requested by the OP.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was reading between the lines. I thought OP wanted the tasks to start at the same time, not just run them in parallel.